# Is there a size limit for database file in Realm Swift?

Tags: ios, realm

My iOS app uses Realm as its local database.
Various data generated by the app is saved in the `default.realm` file.

In tests using actual devices, when the size of `default.realm` exceeds about 6GB, random crashes begin to occur when accessing Realm.
The error message will be different each time, and as the size gets larger, the frequency of crashes will increase.

Is this normal?
Or am I just not using Realm correctly?

Comment: Realm does not have a file size limit and we have Realm files far larger than 6GB. The question is starting to get downvotes and close votes because "random crashes" is vague. It's a good question but there's not enough info. It's important questions include the code that causes the crash along with what the crash is and your troubleshooting. *Or am I just not using Realm correctly?* - is also vague as we don't know how you are using it. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Update the question and we'll take a look!